# System.Printing to return printqueue status - properties never return true

Tags: c#, system.printing, printqueue

I'm using System.Printing to interrogate PrintQueue status - my aim being to obtain status updates & errors, specifically the booleans IsOutOfMemory, NeedUserIntervention, IsOutOfPaper, HasPaperProblem, IsPaperJammed, IsInError, IsPaused, IsBusy, IsPrinting, IsProcessing, IsInitializing, IsDoorOpened etc.  The problem is the properties never return true, even when I know one is true.  Has anyone had success with these properties?  Anyone got any idea what might be wrong or missing here?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess you have to call the `PrintQueue.Refresh` method to update the properties.

Comment: Haha...oh boy...can't believe I missed that.  It's been a long week.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem but calling refresh didn't fix anything for me

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is already answered, another issue might be that the printer doesn't support the mentioned signals. According to the MSDN, these signals are set to false by default.

One has to watch for the `HasToner` flag which is cannot be used to find a problem in cases you're not sure if the printer supports this signal (because it is set to false by default so you can't tell if there's no toner or no indication of toner existence).